# Why is the function $f(t)=(t,t,t,t,t,...) $continuous in the product topology but not the box topology?

Tags: general-topology, box-topology

The function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^\infty$ given by $f(t)=(t,t,t,t,t\dots)$ is said to be not continuous in the box topology but continuous in the product topology.

The example given is $U=(-1,1)\times(-1/2,1/2)\times (-1/3,1/3)\times \dots $. Why does this set show the box topology is not continuous by $f$? We can just take the preimage of $U$ and it would just be $U$ correct? I can see that $(-1/n,1/n)$ converges to $0$ which is closed in $\mathbb R$, but for any specific $\mathbb R_i$ in $\mathbb R^\infty$, we actually do have an open interval even if it is extremely small.

Comment: You should use mathjax. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: $(x_n)_n \in U$ iff for *all* $n$: $x_n \in (-\frac1n, \frac 1n)$. So $f(t) \in U$ iff $\forall n: (f(t))_n = t \in (-\frac1n, \frac1n)$ so $f^{-1}[U]=\bigcap_n (-\frac1n, \frac1n)= \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preimage of $U$ is a set in $\mathbb{R}$ and since $f$ is the identity function in each coordinate, it is given by all the points in $\mathbb{R}$ such that they are smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$ **for every $n$**. Hence you easily see that the preimage is the singleton {0}, which is not open since if it were open, it would contain some interval $(- \delta , \delta)$ for $\delta > 0$. But this would mean that $f( (- \delta , \delta) )\subset U$, getting for each coordinate $(- \delta , \delta) \subset (- 1/n , 1/n)$ **for every $n$**, reaching a contradiction (since if it holds **for every $n$**, then it holds also in the limit that here is zero).

Note that the difference with the product topology is that with the product topology we have only finitely many intervals of the type $(- 1/n , 1/n)$, hence we will always a be able to find a small $\delta > 0$ such that $(- \delta , \delta) \subset (- 1/n , 1/n)$ since now $n$ can take only finitely many values, and you cannot take the limit as $n$ going to infinity.

Comment: If we were talking about the product topology, (−1/n,1/n) would not even be an open set though right? So what would be the the preimage of (−1/n,1/n) in the product topology be?

Comment: Exactly, since a basis element in the product topology is of the form $(- 1/n , 1/n)$ for **finitely many** $n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ for all the rest infinitely many sets (note we are always talking about infinite products, since in finite products box and product topology coincide). For your question, it is a bit badly-posed. You do not have the preimage of $(- 1/n , 1/n)$, since you can only take preimages of infinite products.

Comment: In any case, I see what you mean. The set-theoretical meaning of preimage is the same, so the preimage is still $\{0\}$, that is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but since the set $U$ is not open in the product topology, we are not showing anything for what it concerns the continuity of $f$ in the product topology.

Answer (score 2):

$f^{-1}(U)=\{t: |t| <\frac 1 n \, \forall n\}=\{0\}$ which  is not open.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but can you explain how exactly do we take a preimage of an n tuple to R?

Comment: @willyx888 By the definition of a product set a sequence $(a_n) \in U$ if and only if $a_n \in (-\frac  1n, \frac 1 n)$ for every $n$. I am just applying this definition with $a_n=t$ for all $n$.